# Numbers counter

Tags: c#, arrays

I need help with two similar programs about arrays.

The first program is about that the user can enter any number of numbers between 0 and 9 (input can be made by the
Entering "-1" will be terminated).
After the input is finished, it should be output, how often each number between 0 and 9 was entered.

The 2nd program is about to enter 10 names and save them in a string array. After entering should first all names be output. After that, only those namesare to be issued which were entered more than once.

The Code for the 1. Program :

```
int cnt = 0;
int input;

while (true)
{
    cnt++;

    Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie bitte die {0,1}. Zahl ein (-1 für Ende):", cnt);
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] count = new int[10];
    int[] num = new int[cnt];

    if (input > 9)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (input == -1)
    {
        //Loop through 0-9 and count the occurances
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < num.Length; y++)
            {
                if (num[y] == x)
                    count[x]++;
            }
        }
        //For displaying output only            
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            Console.WriteLine("Number " + x + " appears " + count[x] + " times");
```

And for the 2nd Program :

```
int cnt = 10;
string[] name = new string[11];

for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name Nr.{0,1} eingeben: ", i);
    name[i]++;
    name[i] = Console.ReadLine();

}

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < name.Length; y++)
    {
        if (i == x)
        {
            //For displaying output only            
            for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
                Console.WriteLine("Folgende Namen wurden mehrfach eingegeben : ", name[i]);
            break;
```

The Problem for the 1st Program is that if i type "-1" The number 1-9 always shows that it appeared 0 times and the number 0 always as an example 4 times when i type 4 numbers.

And for the 2nd is that i really dont know how to put strings in arrays. I want to know how to do that, because of the similarity of these 2 programs.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  It looks like you're asking two separate questions, but the rule on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).  Thus you're more likely to get help if you can break your post down into "atomic" questions.  See also [ask] and the [tour].

Comment: **[Navigating through Code using the Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: don't initialize the arrays every loop iteration. Initialize them on the beginning.
Second thing: you must count the numbers before inputting -1. See that you try to increase the count when you enter -1 whereas -1 meant to be program termination I'm assuming.
And third: ask the second problem with string array as another question. You'll get both answers faster that way.
Here's few alteration of your code that needs to be done.

```
int input;
int[] count = new int[10];

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie bitte die {0,1}. Zahl ein (-1 für Ende): ");
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if(input >= 0 && input <= 9)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
        {
            if(x == input)
            {
                count[x] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (input == -1)
    {
        //Input finished, display of numbers appearances.          
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            Console.WriteLine("Number " + x + " appears " + count[x] + " times");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  very much Sir